# Open source linker written in C

Tags: c, linker, elf, portable-executable, mach-o

I am building a programming language that I want to cross compile onto OSX, Windows, and Linux natively (into Mach-O, PE, and ELF formats respectively). Are there any linkers, written in C/C++ that I could integrate with my compiler?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The LLVM Project is a collection of modular and reusable compiler and toolchain technologies. Despite its name, LLVM has little to do with traditional virtual machines, though it does provide helpful libraries that can be used to build them.

see if [this](http://llvm.org/) helps. They have one seperate project for [linker](http://lld.llvm.org/) also. AFAIK this project is well known in community.

Comment: It is indeed very well known -- LLVM is the backend for Clang.

Comment: The linker (`lld`), however, is very primitive unfortunately.